# Selection and Deletion of a tag with specific keyword in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, ads, autoblogged

I use an auto blogging plugin that allows me aggregate RSS feeds from certain sites to fill the gap in my blog in times I don't post in, the idea that posts are injected with ads like AdSense URLs with random dynamic links but usually starts with certain URLS, here is a code snippet:

```
src="http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/669/f/9809/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/mf.gif" border="0" /><br clear='all'/><br /><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/1/rc.img" border="0" /></a><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/2/rc.img" border="0" /></a><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/rc/3/rc.img" border="0" /></a><br /><br /><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/a2.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/a2.img" border="0" /></a><img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/199108411625/u/49/f/9809/c/669/s/3b7b71e8/sc/5/a2t.img" border="0" /><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/techradar/allnews/~4/tWczqbBA1yg" height="1" width="1" /><br />
```

The idea that all injected tags include "*feedsportal.com", how can I select the whole tag line that includes this term and replace it or delete it in WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: Regexp is going to be the tool you'll need here.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy great, the tool hs RegExp Search and Replace tool... what to type in Search and Replace? there is also another option for plain text search and replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all  tags containing the keyword feedsportal.com you can try something like this..

```
// Replace all matches
$str = preg_replace("/\<a.*?feedsportal\.com.*?\>.*?\<\/a\>/is","",$str);

// Collect matches
preg_match_all("/\<a.*?feedsportal\.com.*?\>.*?\<\/a\>/is",$str,$matches);

// Show matches
print "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: The AutoBlogged tool has a search and replace using regular expressions or plain text. In such case how to replace these lines with "space" or null value?